# JQuery...adjust grid offset mid drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable element in JQuery where if you drag it over a certain region, it has a grid, and if you drag it over another region, it doesn't have a grid (or the grid is set to [1,1], same thing). Here is my code:

```
$('#draggableThing').draggable({
        drag:function(){
            if (isOverRegionWthGrid()) 
            {
                $(this).draggable('option','grid',[1,20])
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).draggable('option','grid',[1,1])
            }}})
```

Works great so far. The only problem is, when I drag from the gridless region to the region that has the grid, then the "offset" of the grid is inconsistent. I need it to align with a grid that doesn't change a few pixels up and down every time I drag. It seems that JQuery defines the grid by the initial position of the draggable element. Is there any opinion to give the grid an absolute position, or any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You could look into the [drag start event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) to move the element onto the grid when dragging starts.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ECyUa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, target the grid element and set it to have absolute positioning?

Comment: There is a grid element? I don't know how the underlying code works exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest when switching back to 1, 20 that you move the draggable that it snaps to the coordinates in the grid that you want using modulo division.  For example: (currentX - gridOriginX) % cellWidth, (currentY - gridOriginY) % cellHeight.

In the following example, I just used the original position of the draggable element to determine where the grid *should* be.  I also did this using a droppable "over" event instead of the "drag" event instead.

HTML:

```
<div id="thing">
<div id="draggable5" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag Me</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="thing2">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#draggable5 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
#thing {
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #900;
}
#thing2 {
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var obj = $("#draggable5");
    obj.draggable( {
        grid: [ 1, 20 ], 
    } ).data("init", obj.offset());

    $("#thing").droppable({
        over: function(e, ui) {
            obj = ui.draggable;
            var init = obj.data("init");
            var here = obj.offset();
            here.top = init.top + Math.floor((here.top - init.top) / 20) * 20;
            here.left = init.left + Math.floor((here.left - init.left) / 1) * 1;
            obj.offset(here);
            obj.draggable( "option", "grid", [ 1, 20 ] );
        }
    });
    $("#thing2").droppable({
        over: function(e, ui) {
            obj = ui.draggable;
            obj.draggable( "option", "grid", [ 1, 1 ] );
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qaqDz/3/

Comment: Thanks, finally someone attempted to answer! I will look at this more closely later but at first glance it appears not to work unfortunately. When I drop the element in the region with [1,1] grid, then pick it up, and move it to the [1,20] grid, the grid is off again. This is exactly the problem I have. It works fine if you drag it back and forth but it doesn't work if you drop in the smooth area then drag into the gridded area.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment until just now!  I fiddled around with it a little bit, and found that you can mess with the data that jQueryUI draggable uses when you start the drag.  In particular, if you use $("#draggable5").data("draggable"), you get an object that has the properties originalPageX and originalPageY.  These are the mouse coordinates of when the drag started.  Theoretically if you offset these by the right amount, you can get it to snap back into the grid.  I wasn't able to get it working, but may get time to check it out again later.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I think you might be on to something...I will try messing with these values in a bit.